# how to apply language detection for the standard search page result?

Tags: search, i18n-l10n

I manage an intranet in french and dutch. I do not know how to apply language detection from the result page search/node. I mean I have a result page with both language references and I would like to apply the filter related to language detection and I do not find how ?? Should I use a module or other stuff like search API or Search API Solr Search ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look to the [custom_search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search) module. It allows to customize additional search parameters and also to expose the language of the content to be searched.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I will try the custom_search module. I was just following a training from webwash.net about search API. My goal is to encounter all my employer's needs and I have to follow a lot of trainings. So, Thanks to webwash.net and udemy.com I found the solution.

We have to install search API thanks to which we can create a server and an index that we can thinly configure. But my goal is to set the detection language function for a result page, and I found the solution with the related search API view "/search/content" where I set the filter in question AND it works !!! I have a french result page for the french interface, and I have a dutch result page for the dutch interface !